# Query where all array items are greater than a specified condition

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model which contains an array with dates. I'm using a **`$gte`** operator as a condition to query the collection where all the elements in the array of dates are **`$gte`** a given date.

For example I have this document:

```
{ dates: [
    ISODate("2016-10-24T22:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2017-01-16T23:00:00.000+0000")]
}
```

When I run this query `{dates: {$gte: new Date()}}`, it gives me the whole document as a result. But I want a result where every single array item matches my query, not just one.

Comment: what do you actually mean?

Comment: Uncleared question,please be more specific and add more details so that someone can help you.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I want to query all elements inside an array, and match the query. Now its giving back the document even if one of the elements inside the array matches the query.

Comment: You want documents for values only if the search query matches the values in array, this is what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) and the inversion of your comparison condition:

```
db.test.find({dates: {$not: {$lt: new Date()}}})
```

So this matches docs where it's not the case that there's a `dates` element with a value less than the current time; in other words, all `dates` values are >= the current time.

Comment: Quite clever ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the aggregation framework with the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator that allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

As for the logical condition, there are [Set Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-operators) that you can use since they allow expression that perform set operations on arrays, treating arrays as sets. These couple of these operators namely the **[`$allElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators can be used as the logical condition expression as they work in such a way that if all of the elements in the array actually are **`$gte`** a specified date, then this is a true match and the document is "kept". Otherwise it is "pruned" and discarded.

---

Consider the following examples which demonstrate the above concept:

**Populate Test Collection**

```
db.test.insert([
    { dates: [
        ISODate("2016-10-24T22:00:00.000+0000"), 
        ISODate("2017-01-16T23:00:00.000+0000")]
    } ,
    { dates: [
        ISODate("2017-01-03T22:00:00.000+0000"), 
        ISODate("2017-01-16T23:00:00.000+0000")]
    } 
])
```

**[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** with **[`$setEquals`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/#exp._S_setEquals)**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "dates": { "$gte": new Date() } } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$allElementsTrue": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$dates",
                            "as": "date",
                            "in": { "$gte": [ "$$date", new Date() ] }
                        }
                    } 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581899dda450d81cb7d87d3a"),
    "dates" : [ 
        ISODate("2017-01-03T22:00:00.000Z"), 
        ISODate("2017-01-16T23:00:00.000Z")
    ]
}
```

---

Another not-so elegant approach would be to use **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** (as a last resort) with the **[`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** method:

```
db.test.find({ "$where": function(){ 
    return this.dates.every(function(date) {
        return date >= new Date();
    })}
})
```

---